# BiqQuery Error: Cannot join on repeated field 'customDimensions.value'

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have the following SQL statement, in short, `table` contains a list of `id`s that I need to get the website behavior for the past year. These `id`s should match `customDimensions.value`

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitNumber, totals.pageviews, customDimensions.value as client_id
FROM (
SELECT * FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_],
                    TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01'),
                    TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01'))
                    )
WHERE customDimensions.index = 2 AND customDimensions.value IN (SELECT STRING(id) FROM [table])
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

I get the error:

> Error: Cannot join on repeated field customDimensions.value

Comment: have you considered moving to bigquery standard sql? that would really simplify your life especially in such cases

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Apologies, I've read the answer, but it was early morning and I moved along. I try to consistently mark/upvote all answers and the help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: sure, no problem :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are still with BigQuery Legacy SQL so below is for legacy sql

Assuming that the rest of your original query does what you want  - it addresses below error

> Error: Cannot join on repeated field customDimensions.value

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitNumber, totals.pageviews, customDimensions.value AS client_id
FROM FLATTEN((
SELECT * FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_],
                    TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01'),
                    TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01'))
                    ), customDimensions)
WHERE customDimensions.index = 2 AND customDimensions.value IN (SELECT STRING(id) FROM [table])
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```